# How to find out the number of records in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a scaffold help requisition. There is a status field. Each request can have 3 statuses (pending, in_progress, finished), implemented through enum. It is necessary to write methods that will count the number of requests with each status. For example, method A counts how many total helper prequests with status 0 (pending). I understand that there is nothing complicated about this, but I can't understand and could use some help.

Comment: I don't know that you even need methods for this. 

Using enums provides a scope for the status, so you could just call, for example, `YourModel.in_progress.count`. That seems pretty idiomatic to me, and saves the nine lines of code needed to turn the counts into separate methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this on your model:

```
def self.pending_count
 where(status: 0).count
end


def self.in_progress_count
 where(status: 1).count
end

def self.finished_count
 where(status: 2).count
end
```

Then you can just call `Model.pending_count` (or the other methods) wherever you need it.